# Align a hex text file at 9 bytes each line

Tags: bash, sed, awk, python

I want to align the selected portion of a text file at 9 bytes each column.

For example suppose my text file looks like below.

```
00 2f c6 b8 29 fd 02 37 11  00 9f 74 34 0b 60 72 38 20  00 9e 61 33 8e ab 8a c0 09 
00 fa f0 66 6d 0c 44 d6 24 00 a1 11 9d a2 13 a5 b3 83
```

I want the resulting file to be like

```
00 2f c6 b8 29 fd 02 37 11 
00 9f 74 34 0b 60 72 38 20 
00 9e 61 33 8e ab 8a c0 09 
00 fa f0 66 6d 0c 44 d6 24 
00 a1 11 9d a2 13 a5 b3 83
```

What is the easiest way to do this? Is it possible to do it in `bash` using `sed` or `awk` maybe?

Or a better way to frame the question will be I have formatted my input sequence as seen below.

```
00 88 ec 40 bf 94 1d 63
f4 00 04 1c 4e 06 d0 2c
2e f9 00 90 03 51 d5 71
cc 86 79 00 24 6b 22 30
b6 66 0f 5f 00 c1 cd a5
c8 45 b9 88 85 00 c0 de
ae 47 d9 91 f9 d3 00 5b
```

That is 8 bytes each line.If you notice carefully in line 1 first byte is `00`.in line 2 the second byte is `00` and in line 3 the third byte is `00`.I want the align the whole file so that the all the lines begin with a `00`.

Comment: P.S. To format your code so it looks pretty, highlight the code and press `CTRL+K` or click on the icon that looks like a `{ }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work regardless of how many bytes are on a single line

```
sed ':a $!N;s/\n/ /;ta;s/\(\(\([[:xdigit:]]\)\{2\} *\)\{8\}\([[:xdigit:]]\)\{2\}\) */\1\n/g'
```

#### Input

```
$ cat alignbyte
00 2f c6
b8 29 fd 02
37 11 00 9f 74 34 0b 60 72 38
20 00 9e 61 33 8e ab 8a c0 09
00 fa f0 66
6d 0c 44 d6 24
00 a1 11 9d a2 13 a5 b3 83
```

#### Output

```
$ sed ':a $!N;s/\n/ /;ta;s/\(\(\([[:xdigit:]]\)\{2\} *\)\{8\}\([[:xdigit:]]\)\{2\}\) */\1\n/g' alignbyte
00 2f c6 b8 29 fd 02 37 11
00 9f 74 34 0b 60 72 38 20
00 9e 61 33 8e ab 8a c0 09
00 fa f0 66 6d 0c 44 d6 24
00 a1 11 9d a2 13 a5 b3 83
```

---

I just noticed that your input file seems to have two blank spaces after each set of 9 bytes, except for the very last set. If that is a typo and all sets of 9 bytes *are* indeed separated by two spaces then the command to get what you want is simply this:

```
sed 's/  /\n/g' file
```

Comment: Like the other answer, this won't work if the input has a line with `n%9 != 0` bytes.

Comment: that is true.I have formatted my output to be 8 bytes long in each line and this sed expression does not work.

Comment: @liv2hak see updated answer which is byte-per-line agnostic

Answer (score 4):

One approach that doesn't care about the exact shape of the input is to split it into one item per line then group items in the desired number.

```
tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' |
awk '
    NR % 9 != 1 {printf " "}
    {printf "%s", $0}
    NR % 9 == 0 {print ""}
    END {if (NR % 9) print ""}'
```

If you don't mind an extra space at the end of the line, you can simplify the `awk` code a bit:

```
tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' |
awk '
    {printf "%s ", $0}
    NR % 9 == 0 {print ""}
    END {if (NR % 9) print ""}'
```

If your input has no blank lines and all items are the same width, then there's a simpler solution: put everything on one line then perform line folding.

```
{ tr -s '\n' ' '; echo; } | fold -w 27
```

If you have the `fmt` utility, it can combine both subtasks:

```
fmt -w 27
```

Comment: Interesting: `tr -s` ... Translation occurs before the Squeeze... very handy

Comment: very nice. Another alternative (to `fold`, `fmt`, or `awk`) would be `paste -sd "$(printf '% *s' 10 '\n')"`

Answer (score 0):

A basic trick:

```
grep -o ".. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .." your-file.txt
```

If the lines length may not be multiple of 9 hexa bytes, then remove the CRCL:

```
tr -d '\n\r' < your-file.txt | grep -o ".. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .."
```

If the file may contain consecutive spaces:

```
tr -s ' \n\r' ' ' < your-file.txt | grep -o ".. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .."
```

I am appreciate the complex `sed`/`awk` programming answers.
Here, I propose readable tricks using basic tools.

Comment: This will only work if each line of the input has a multiple of nine bytes.

Comment: that is true.in case of my file that is not true.is there a better way to do that.?

Comment: Dear @Kevin, I have just added `tr` to clean up the input file

Comment: Dear @liv2hak I have just added `tr` to clean up the input file

Answer (score 0):

This might work you (in the second instance where each line is 8 bytes long):

```
 sed '$!N;s/\n/ /;s/ /\n/9;P;D' file
```

In the first instance (variable length records):

```
fmt -w27 file
```

Or with GNU sed:

```
sed 'L27;d' file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk  '{gsub ("00","\n00") ;print $0}' myfile
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this relies on the actual data being exactly like the sample data by having `00` in exactly the right place.